# How to make seekbar thumb draggable

Tags: android, seekbar

I am using a seekbar which had maximum of 2. However whenever i tap the other marked points thumb moves and even when I try to drag the thumb it directly comes up the other position. Please tell if there is any kind of animation by which i can show seekbar thumb dragging along with the touch .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no animation for that. But you could just raise the maximum to 200 and then programmatically divide the progress by 100, round it to 1 or 2 and then set create a timer/handler which sets the progress like an animation until it reaches the rounded value.